# USB and iPhone. In an iPhone app, USB is not connected to a computer?

Tags: iphone, usb

I have this scenario where I have Windows Mobile smartphones that talk in low level to the USB port of a device that is not a computer. I now have to do this from an iPhone. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is not currently supported with Apple's SDK.  However, in the 3.0 release (June 2009) it will be supported.

Learn more here:
http://www.apple.com/iphone/preview-iphone-os/

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that will be supported by the upcoming 3.0 software. There are some caveats however. You will have to use the 30-pin connector provided by Apple and the protocols that accompany it.

For more info, check out: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 3.0 SDK supports this, through its [External Accessory](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/program/sdk.html) API.